# File sharing solutions for LAN network?

Tags: samba

If I want to share my Films/Videos on LAN, what should I choose? My solution would be Samba.

Q: what else is there? ( NFS is very bad - security (?) + in many cases it could freeze the clients.. )

The main purpose is that it must be a "mountable" solution - so the clients can see a "folder" (the "folder" is actually the shared folder on a server - READ ONLY!). And they don't need to first copy the e.g.: AVI files to their PC because they could play them directly from the "folder".

Comment: I narrowed your question to just the part about NFS security; "what should I use" is subjective. If you want suggestions you need to say what specific features you're looking for

Comment: Define “security”. What are your requirements? (And also what NFS version, and what implementations on both the server and the client(s).)

Comment: If you want to insist that "nfs is very bad" and that "your solution would be samba", please just do whatever you feel like. If you want input from this community of experts, please ask questions and listen to the answers.

Comment: NFS security is addressable and it doesn't freeze clients. Clients freeze when their file systems become unavailable, but this would happen for any file system. I use NFS for the root file system of dozens of machines on a single network and don't have a problem with anything freezing, you are only talking about accessing media with it. It's still my #1 suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what you read about NFS security only applies to old versions of nfs and public networks. If your network is closed limited to trusted user usage you don't have to worry as much, and recent versions of nfs include all kinds of security measures. If you were really paranoid you could tunnel it over ssh.

All that to say the objection is surmountable and nothing else in your question gives us any clue how to answer it or what to recommend. Maybe if you described your situation a little better a technology could be forwarded.

Comment: 1+ I currently use NFS to share (read-only) my media with the rest of my LAN (Unix and Mac), works great.  I think how secure it is depends on your setup, but if used correctly I think it is as secure as any other solution.